# Disable scrollable event on a specified id

Tags: javascript

I have a responsive navigation on my website. And, this js code is for smooth scrolling within my webpage.

```
$(function(){$("a[href*=#]:not([href=#])").click(function() {
if(location.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")==this.pathname.replace(/^\//,"")
&&location.hostname==this.hostname){
var target=$(this.hash);
target=target.length?target:$("[name="+this.hash.slice(1)+"]");
if(target.length){
$("html,body").animate({scrollTop:target.offset().top},1000);return false}}})});
```

When i create a link `<a href="#topWrapper">Scroll to Topwrapper</a>`, i can scroll it smoothly to the `div` as long as the div name is `#topWrapper` or `#whatever`. I have also an id name `navi` in my navigation. I would like to ask that, is there anyway i can disable the id in this js code so that it doesn't scroll when i click on the hamburger icon to open the menu? Thank you!

Hope you understand what i am asking as English is not my primary language. Thank you!

**Update:**

```
<nav class="menu" id="navi">
  <ul>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="/">About</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Our Vision</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Services</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Latest New</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Our Blog</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="/">Gallery</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Kitchen Cabinet</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Melamine ABS Kitchen Cabinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Acrylic Door Kitchen Cabinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">3G Glass Door Kitchen Cabinet</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">4G Glass Door Kitchen Cabinet</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Wardrobe Design</a>
          <ul class="sub-menu">
            <li><a href="#">Swing Door Wardrobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sliding Door Wardrobe</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Walk In Closet</a></li>
          </ul>
        </li>
        <li><a href="#">TV Cabinet</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Study Table Design</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3D Cabinet Design</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Others Cabinet Design</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Materials</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Doors</a>
          <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Melamine ABS Door</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">3G Glass Door</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Acrylic Door</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">4G Glass Door</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Membrane Pressed</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Multi-Layer Ply Laminated</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Carcass</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">Compressed Wood</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Blockboard</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solid Wood</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Aluminium</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Worktop</a>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">HPL Worktop</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Solid Surface</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Granite Stone</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Quartz Stone</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Promotion</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
    <li><a href="#">Kitchen Cabinet</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Wardrobe</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Appliances</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Extended Promotion</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
    <li class="has-sub-menu"><a href="#">Contact</a>
      <ul class="sub-menu">
        <li><a href="#">Contact Information</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Enquiry Form</a></li>
    <li><a href="#">Meet Our Designers</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Facebook</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">Twitter</a></li>
        <li class="share"><a href="#">Whatsapp</a></li>
      </ul>
    </li>
  </ul>
</nav>
```

**Js Code for navigation:**

```
 $(document).ready(function(e){
var t=$("#navi"),a=$(".menu-link"),l=$(".has-sub-menu > a");
a.click(function(e){e.preventDefault(),a.toggleClass("active"),t.toggleClass("active")}),l.click(function(e){e.preventDefault();
var t=$(this);t.toggleClass("active").next("ul").toggleClass("active")}),e.preventDefault()});
```

Comment: What is the id of the hamburger button? If you tell me, I will write an answer :)

Comment: Your English is better than already half of the people on this site :)

Comment: Thank you for posting the HTML :)

Comment: @www139, i have updated the question. Kindly check it out. Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

Do:

```
document.getElementById("desired-id-name").addEventListener('click', function(){
  return false;  // does nothing
});
```

---

**EDIT 1:**
Since you are using jQuery, here is a jQuery version:

```
$("#desired-id-name").click(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Make sure to add this inside:

```
$(function(){ ... };
```

---

**EDIT 2:**

```
$("#desired-id-name").scroll(function(){
  return false;
});
```

Docs: https://api.jquery.com/scroll/

Comment: thank you for your updated answer! But, should i put this code in new line of my existing js code or, is there i need to put in certain line?

Comment: `$(function(){$("desired-id-name").click(function(){
  return false;
});};` is this the way you telling?

Comment: @Jornes Yes. Try that.

Comment: @RahulDesai Good answer! Just what I would have written +1 :)

Comment: @RahulDesai, i tried your updated quote. It still scrolls. And my responsive menu not going to open. Do you need my full code so that you can figure it out?

Comment: @Jornes Are you trying to disable scrolling or disable click? If you can provide more code, That would be great.

Comment: @RahulDesai, yes! I wanted to disable scrolling only. I have get my question updated. Kindly check it out. Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Jornes Please check **EDIT 2** in my answer above. Make sure to use `#desired-id-name`. I missed `#` earlier.

Comment: @Jornes Let me know if it helped.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/96410/discussion-between-jornes-and-rahul-desai).